# Execute a program that creates a pdf file then writes it to a folder with response

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I am trying to produce a pdf file from an external program, then run it with Response. This code works perfectly on my localhost while debugging, but won't produce the file on my clients' server (Server 2008). It successfully runs on the server from a DOS command, but hangs on the aspx page.

```
String outputpath = Convert.ToString(Session["PDFOutputPath"]);
String output = outputpath + "barcode_reports.pdf";
System.IO.FileInfo myfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(output);
if (myfile.Exists)
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(output);
}       
String rpt = this.ReportButtonList.SelectedValue;
String _path = Convert.ToString(Session["ReportPath"]);
String parms = "'" + @outputpath + "','" + @rpt + "'";

System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();        
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @_path;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "run_reports.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "barcode_reports " + @parms;        
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;        

p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();

System.IO.FileInfo myfile2 = new System.IO.FileInfo(output);

if (myfile2.Exists)
{

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myfile2.Name);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myfile2.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "application//pdf";
    Response.TransmitFile(myfile2.FullName);
    Response.End();
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Clear();

}
```

I know that the process starts because it triggers the task manager process and I know the output folder is accessible because the initial erase works fine.  Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Does it throw any exceptions on the server? Or may be other errors in EventManager?

Comment: I can't get to their server right now.  I will check tomorrow.  Thanks for responding.